# reRender standard controller object list

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender

I'm using standard controller on my visualforce page to get list of records like below

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" 
           standardController="customObj__c" 
           recordSetVar="customObjs" 
           extensions="customCtrl">

      <apex:form id="the_form">
          <apex:pageBlock>
              <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!customObjs}" var="cs">
                  <apex:column headerValue="Actions">
                      <apex:commandLink action="{!getDetails}" reRender="the_form">
                          <span>Edit</span>
                          <apex:param name="csId" value="{!cs.id}" assignTo="{!csId}"/>
                      </apex:commandLink>
                  </apex:column>
                  <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!cs.name}"/>
              </apex:pageBlockTable>
               <apex:pagemessages id="msg" />
          </apex:pageBlock>


          <apex:pageBlock id="editPage" title="Edit">

              <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                  <apex:commandButton value="Save"
                                      action="{!custom_save}" 
                                      reRender="the_form"/>
              </apex:pageBlockButtons>
              <apex:pageBlockSection >
                      <apex:inputField value="{!customObj.name}"/>
                  </apex:repeat>
              </apex:pageBlockSection>
          </apex:pageBlock>
      </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
```

When I click on Save button, I reRender thte form, but table list info not changed, I want to update the list to get latest updated data.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the form in an apex:outputpanel tag. Assign the tag the id and the rerender attribute. Good luck.

Comment: a good technique, but this should not be required.